# How do I return all of a dictionary's keys, and print them out side of the function in Python 3.4?

Tags: function, python-3.x, dictionary, return

Here is a section of my Python 3.4 code. It does exactly what I want it to but I would like to have the variable "ingredients" and the keys from my dictionary "lemon_drizzle" to Return so that i can use them outside of the function.

```
how_lemon= int(input('How many lemon drizzle cakes would you like to
bake?'))

#list of the ingredients for cakes
lemon_drizzle={
     'Double Cream':140,
     'Lemon Zest':3,
     'Salt':1,
     'Baking Power':0.5}
plain_flour2 = lemon_drizzle['Plain Flour']= 120
sugar2 = lemon_drizzle['Sugar']= 140
unsalted_butter2 = lemon_drizzle['Unsalted Butter']= 40
free_eggs2 = lemon_drizzle['Free Range Eggs']= 1


def function_ingredients(cake, how_many):
   for key,val in cake.items():
    ingredients = val * how_many

    '''
    I want this to return 'ingredients' and all the keys
    so that it does exactly the same this, but outside the function.
    '''

    print(ingredients, key)



print('\nFor your lemon drizzle cakes you will need:\n')    
lemon_ingredients = function_ingredients(lemon_drizzle, how_lemon)
```

Thank you for listening to, and hopefully answering my question! P.S this is prob a really simple problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation problem. Try this:

```
def function_ingredients(cake, how_many):
    for key,val in cake.items():
        ingredients = val * how_many  
#    I want this to return 'ingredients' and all the keys
#    so that it does exactly the same this, but outside the function.
        print(ingredients, key)
```

I also replaced your multiline string literal (the one with triple quotes) by Python comments. If you really want the multiline string, be careful to indent it correctly.

Also

```
plain_flour2 = lemon_drizzle['Plain Flour']= 120
```

can probably be replaced with:

```
lemon_drizzle['Plain Flour']= 120
```